# python tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

Tags: python, temporary-files

i'm trying to create a temporary file using this instruction:

```
tfile, filename = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().
```

unfortunately, an exception this thrown:

```
tfile, filename = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: Seems like this function returns only one object, and you're expecting 2: tfile and filename

Comment: that's it, thanks friend !